# Exceptions & C-style strings

Tags: c++, exception

I've problem with exceptions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <exception>

class except :public std::exception
{
    char* err;
public:
    except(const char* s) noexcept
    {
        err = new char[strlen(s) + 1];
        strcpy(err, s);
        err[strlen(s)] = 0; //is it necessary??
    }
    virtual const char* what() noexcept
    {return err;}
    virtual ~except() noexcept
    {delete err;}
};

double div(const double& a, const double& b) noexcept
{
    if (b == 0.0)
        throw except("DIVIDED BY 0");
    return a / b;
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        std::cout << div(5.0, 0.0);
    }
    catch (std::exception &ex)
    {
        std::cout << ex.what();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to print "DIVIDED BY 0" but I get:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'except'
  what():  std::exception
Aborted

Process returned 134 (0x86)
```

Shall I put `noexcept` in every function/member function that doesn't throw any exceptions?

Is `err[strlen(s)] = 0` necessary? (in except::except(const char* s))

Comment: Why don’t you use std::string? Better: derive from std::runtime_error.

Comment: 1) Do you know what C-strings are? They are null-terminated strings. "_Is `err[strlen(s)] = 0` necessary?_" No, not really, since [std::strcpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy) includes it, when copying the string. However, such line causes no harm. 2) `delete err;` is undefined behavior. It should be deleted as `delete[] err;`, since it was `new`ed with `new[]`.

Comment: You're using exceptions, a somewhat middle to advanced topic in C++, yet you're using C-style strings.  Why?

Comment: And your except ctor is not actually noexcept as it invokes new.

Comment: Also, `div` is throwing an exception, so definitely not `noexcept`, right?

Comment: Also using the wrong form of `delete`.  It should be `delete [] err`.  But why even do all of this when you could simply use `std::string`.

Comment: Re: `err[strlen(s)] = 0; //is it necessary??` You should read the documentation for `strcpy`.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to print "DIVIDED BY 0" but I get: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'except'

```
double div(const double& a, const double& b) noexcept
```

You are claiming that you won’t throw an exception, but you are lying. The result is the call to std::terminate when you actually throw.

Comment: After removing `noexcept`: `ex.what()` returns `std::exception`. If I change in except `:public std::exception` to `:public std::runtime_error` it works, why?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is a actually twofold. Firstly, as @manni66 suggests, `div` should not be declared `noexcept` and this does cause a run-time error, but removing it does not solve the issue.

The second problem is that `what` has been declared:

```
virtual const char* what() noexcept;
```

whereas it's declared in `std::exception` as:

```
virtual const char* what() const noexcept;
```

and this difference in signature means that when it's caught by the handler for `std::exception`, it calls `std::exception::what()` and not `except::what()`

A couple of points worth mentioning:

1. Ensure that your function overloads exactly match those in the base class.
2. If you are expecting a certain type of exception to be thrown then try to catch that first with a specific handler and use an appropriate name for the exception for clarity.
3. As others have mentioned, please try to use the `std::string` class if you can. It will make things easier and safer. Although in this case, as point two eludes to, a string member is not really necessary as the class is specific enough not to need further qualification.
4. Don't create an exception class unless it's adding some specific value (though the *value*, may simply be that you want to specifically catch a certain type of exception and handle in a certain way.) If you wanted a more general exception then `std::runtime_error` or in this case `std::overflow_error` would be decent choices and both take a `std::string` as an argument to the constructor, so no need to create your own exception class.

For example:

```
#include <exception>
using namespace std;


class divide_by_zero : public std::exception
{
public:
    virtual const char* what() const noexcept { return "DIVIDED BY 0"; }
};

double div(const double& a, const double& b)
{
    if (b == 0.0)
        throw divide_by_zero();
    return a / b;
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        std::cout << div(5.0, 0.0);
    }
    catch (divide_by_zero &ex)
    {
        std::cout << ex.what();
    }
    catch (std::exception &ex)
    {
        std::cout << ex.what();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
DIVIDED BY 0
```

Comment: I know that I shouldn't use C-style string & avoid creating own exceptions classes if it's not necessary. I just want to know why isn't it working. Adding `noexcept` doesn't solve problem, output is still `std::exception`. (I know that I can just use `throw std::runtime_error("DIVIDED BY 0")`)

Comment: Just take your code and (a) remove `noexcept` _only_ fron the div function and (b) make sure that your `what ()` has exactly the same signature as `std::exception` (ie must be const) even without the above extra suggestions it should work